# Provider tag in react causing blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make a webpage using React js and use redux template. I am trying to wrap my component around < Provider >. After wrapping i get a blank page. I tried using React developer tools that too appears blank. here is my code.Here is the error i am getting

```
 Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.
at createStore (createStore.js:55:1)
at ./src/index.js (index.js:9:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
at startup:7:1
at startup:7:1
```

Main.js

```
   import Title from './Title'
   import Photowall from './Photowall'
   import AddPhoto from './AddPhoto'
   import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
   class Main extends Component{

   constructor(){
 super()
this.state= {
    posts : [{
        id: "0",
        description: "beautiful landscape",
        imageLink: "https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/none/path/sa6549607c78f5c11/image/i4eeacaa2dbf12d6d/version/1490299332/most-beautiful-landscapes-in-europe-lofoten-european-best-destinations-copyright-iakov-kalinin.jpg" +
        "3919321_1443393332_n.jpg"
        }, {
        id: "1",
        description: "Aliens???",
        imageLink: "https://s3.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/rocket.jpg"
        }, {
        id: "2",
        description: "On a vacation!",
        imageLink: "https://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2017/08/24/104670887-VacationExplainsTHUMBWEB.1910x1000.jpg"
        }],
      
    }
    this.removePhoto=this.removePhoto.bind(this)
    }

removePhoto(postRemoved){
    console.log(postRemoved.description)
   this.setState((state) => ({
        posts: state.posts.filter(post => post !== postRemoved)
      }))
}

addPhoto(postSubmitted){
    this.setState(state => ({
        posts:state.posts.concat([postSubmitted])
    }))
}

componentDidMount(){
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
    console.log(prevState.posts)
    console.log(this.state)
    }
   render() {        
   return (

    <div> 
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
        <div>
            <Title title={'Photowall'}/>
            <Photowall posts={this.state.posts} onRemovePhoto={this.removePhoto} onNavigate={this.navigate}/>
         </div>
   
   )}/>
 
  <Route path="/AddPhoto" render={({history})=>(
     <AddPhoto onAddPhoto={(addedPost)=>{
         this.addPhoto(addedPost)
        history.push('/')
     }}/>
    )}/>
      </div>

)
}
}    
export default Main
```

AddPhoto.js

```
        import React, { Component } from "react"

        class AddPhoto extends Component{
        constructor(){
        super()
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        }

        handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const imageLink = event.target.elements.link.value
        const description = event.target.elements.description.value
        const post = {
        id:0,
        description:description,
        imageLink:imageLink          
        }
        if(description && imageLink){
        this.props.onAddPhoto(post)
        }
        }

        render(){
        return(
        <div>
        <h1>Photowall</h1>
        <div className="form">
         <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Link" name="link"/>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Description" name="description"/>
         <button>Post</button>
    
         </form>
    
     </div>
     </div>
     )
     }
     }

   export default AddPhoto
```

Photo.js

```
     import React, {Component} from "react";
     import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
     function Photo(props){
     const post =props.post
     return <figure className="figure">
             <img className="photo" src={post.imageLink} alt={post.description}/>
             <figcaption><p>{post.description}</p></figcaption>
             <div className="button-container">
             <button className="remove-button" onClick={()=>{ 
                props.onRemovePhoto(post);
            }}> Remove </button>
             </div>
      </figure>

      }

      Photo.propTypes={
      post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      onRemovePhoto:PropTypes.func.isRequired
      }
      export default Photo
```

Photowall.js

```
       import React,{ Component} from 'react'
       import Photo from './Photo'
       import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
       import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
       function Photowall(props){
       return <div>
       <Link className='addIcon' to='/AddPhoto' ><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0Ij48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTIgMGMtNi42MjcgMC0xMiA1LjM3My0xMiAxMnM1LjM3MyAxMiAxMiAxMiAxMi01LjM3MyAxMi0xMi01LjM3My0xMi0xMi0xMnptNyAxNGgtNXY1aC00di01aC01di00aDV2LTVoNHY1aDV2NHoiLz48L3N2Zz4="></img> </Link>
    {/*<button onClick={props.onNavigate} className='addIcon'> + </button>*/}
        <div className='photo-grid'>
        {props.posts.map((post, index) => <Photo key={index} post={post} onRemovePhoto={props.onRemovePhoto}/>)}
       </div>
       </div>
       }
       Photowall.propTypes={
       posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
       onRemovePhoto:PropTypes.func.isRequired
       }
       export default Photowall
```

index.js

```
       import React, { Component } from 'react';
       import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
       import Main from './Components/Main'
       import './styles/stylesheet.css'
       import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
       import {createStore} from 'redux'
       import rootReducer from './redux/reducer'
       import {Provider} from "react-redux";
       const store = createStore(rootReducer)



   ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><BrowserRouter><Main/></BrowserRouter></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

reducer.js

```
    import posts from '../data/posts'

     const postReducer = function posts(state = posts,action){
     return state

     }

     export default postReducer
```

Comment: Do you have any other errors?

Comment: i am using react 17. Here are list of all the errors:   Warning: Please use `require("history").createBrowserHistory` instead of `require("history/createBrowserHistory")`. Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release.react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.
Please update the following components: BrowserRouter, Router

Please update the following components: Provider, Router

Comment: I am using react 17.